# Is every $f\colon\mathbb{R\to R}$ can be written as the pointwise difference of two injective functions?

Tags: set-theory

Let $\mathscr {F}=\{f\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb R\colon f \ \text{is injective}\}$ by $\mathbb {R}^\mathbb{R}$ all functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R.$ My question Is the following true?
$$
\mathscr F-\mathscr F=\mathbb R^\mathbb R
$$
My guess, it is correct. Does anyone has a counterexample? any idea will be appreciated

Comment: So you're asking whether every function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is the difference of two injective functions?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Yes this is actually my question

Comment: The characteritic of the rationals?

Comment: I think this is true. You can construct the two injective functions for a given $f$ by recursion, I think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Certainly assuming the axiom of choice we can do this. Here's an outline of how to do this (filling in the gaps is a good exercise):

Fixing $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, enumerate the reals as $(r_\alpha)_{\alpha<\mathfrak{c}}$. Now recursively for each $\alpha<\mathfrak{c}$ pick reals $b_\alpha, c_\alpha$ which have not already been used such that $c_\alpha-b_\alpha=f(r_\alpha)$ (these exist since we've only used $<\mathfrak{c}$ reals so far).

Now let $g(r_\alpha)=c_\alpha$ and $h(r_\alpha)=b_\alpha$.

---

In the absence of choice, the situation is less clear - I suspect in that case the answer is **no**, that is, that it is consistent with ZF (= set theory without choice) that there is a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which is not the difference of two injective functions. However, such consistency proofs are rather difficult, and I don't see one immediately.

*("Paging Karagila, Asaf Karagila ...")*

Comment: Yes yes, I'm already thinking about that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Hehehe.

Comment: I think you mean $c_\alpha - b_\alpha = f(r_\alpha)$.  And filling in the gaps here = transfinite induction?

Comment: @JairTaylor Yes, fixed (and yes, filling in the gaps just amounts to making the implicit transfinite induction precise - e.g. how *exactly* do we define the $c$s and $b$s).

Comment: What if we want $g,h$ bijective?

Comment: Nice, this is what I was thinking about too, but I had no time to write it up better. I’m a big fan of constructing examples by transfinite recursion. Well-order everything in sight!

Comment: For the question without choice, note that having a decomposition of $(x,y) \mapsto x$ into two injective functions $h,g \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ suffices to have one for all functions (namely, for $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, consider $h(f(x),x)$ and $g(f(x),x)$). I find the question very interesting. What about the weaker version: Is there a Borel function that cannot be decomposed into to Borel injections? Is there an easy way to see this?